# About the unity group in a domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(R,+,\cdot)$ be a domain. Is it true that every finite subgroup of $\, \mathcal{U}(R)$ is cyclic?

---

$(R,+,\cdot)$ is a ring with no zero divisors

$\, \mathcal{U}(R)$ = the set of all invertible elements in the ring $( R,+,\cdot)$

---

I know how to prove this if the ring is commutative:

Let $H$ be a finite subgroup of $\, \mathcal{U}(R)$ and $m = \mathop {\max }\limits_{x \in H} ord(x)$. Then $ord(y) | m$ for every $y \in G$, therefore the polynomial $X^m-1 \in R[X]$ has $|H|$ roots. But the polynomial $X^m-1$ has no more than $m$ roots, which implies that $|H| \le m$. But $m | |H|$, therefore $m=|H|$ and $H$ is cyclic, as it has an element of order $m$.

But I don't know how to deal with the other case.

Comment: Do you mean "integral domain"? A domain may refer just to a ring with $1\neq 0$ that has no zero divisors, and not assume commutativity. E.g.,[Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_(ring_theory))

Comment: In the ring of integer quaternions, $\{\pm 1,\pm i,\pm j,\pm k\}$ is a finite subgroup of the unit group that is not cyclic.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Just because they were wrong once, everything else they say (especially on wholly unrelated things) is suddenly invalid?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Mixing up $R$ and $\Bbb R$ is common enough on this site. Wanting people to not answer in comments is _completely_ unrelated. Being wrong on one of them does not make someones opinion on the other any less worth. At least in my opinion. The way I read your response to amWhy, you disagree with me on this. I am not commenting about your character at all, I am merely wondering whether you really do disagree with me on this issue, and asked for a clarification. (I agree that "If you dare" was a over the top, but it is a form of confrontationalism I am prone to demonstrate myself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is false without commutativity. Let $R$ be the integer quaternions, 
$$R= \{a+bi+cj+dk\mid a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$
and take $\{\pm 1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$ as the finite subgroup of its unit group.